# How do I can I get notified of an object collision and object trigger in Box2D?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, events, game-engine, box2d

Unity3D has the `OnCollisionEnter2D`, `OnCollisionExit2D`, `OnTriggerEnter2D` etc. However, I am using Box2D and am looking for a way to implement something similar or the same in my C++ project, but I do not know how. I saw something about implementing a listener but I believe it was for the whole world. I am looking to report these events only to the code that physics body is attached to.

Comment: Was your problem solved? Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling an event listener is necessary for collision events in Box2D, as explained in [this video](https://youtu.be/pJ_M_fACtB8). *Alternatively*, you could implement your own collision logic. For rectangular hitboxes, that would look something like this: (***Please note:** this only works for rectangles with no rotation relative to the screen.*)

```
if (rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.w &&
    rect1.x + rect1.w > rect2.x &&
    rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.h &&
    rect1.h + rect1.y > rect2.y) 
{
    // collision detected
} 
else 
{
    // no collision
}
```

For circles, that would look something like this:

```
auto dx = (circle1.x + circle1.radius) - (circle2.x + circle2.radius);
auto dy = (circle1.y + circle1.radius) - (circle2.y + circle2.radius);
auto distance = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

if (distance < circle1.radius + circle2.radius) 
{
    // collision detected
}
else 
{
    // no collision
}
```

You can see these detection algorithms in more detail [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection).

Comment: I want to do it like the video explained. I did not get exactly how to do this. Let's say I override the class, what then? Is it possible I can assign a contact listener to a specific body?

Comment: Thank you for your post! Unfortunately, I could not use the code you provided. I had to go with the content of the video. For anyone else facing similar problems, I am going to elaborate more on the answer. Create a class that inherits from ```b2ContactListener```. Call ```SetContactListener(b2ContactListener* contactListener)``` for the world. You should pass an object of the custom b2ContactListener to this function. Make sure that the object you passed was allocated in the heap unless your contact listener is global. Then, follow it with adding some user data to the body.

Comment: @ChristopherBarriosAgosto Sorry for not responding, but glad to be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to the api [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html), `OnCollisionEnter2D` is bind to the object itself, so it meet your needs.

Simply, you can add collision detection code in the ego object and do something when a collision is detected.

```cpp
class Car {

  void process() {
    if (checkCollision(box2d)) {
      // do something
    }
  }
};
```